# Elasticsearch Java-Play Framework - in query BoolQueryBuilder to write a query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, playframework-2.0, elasticsearch-java-api

Here is my ES document structure

```
admin_faq
  - faq_id
  - title
  - is_active
```

**Case 1 Filter**
have comma separated `FAQ id's  2,3,4.`
Split id's using

```
        String[] array = assignedCategories.split(",");
        for (String value : array) {
            queryBuilderPost.should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("faq_id", value));
        }
```

In case 1 this query working fine for me and only show the faq's where faq id is `2,3,4`

**Case 2**
when I have another filter like is_active so its return the all data where is_active=Y and also related to comma separated id's FAQs

```
        String[] array = assignedCategories.split(",");
        for (String value : array) {
            queryBuilderPost.should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("faq_id", value));
        }
        queryBuilderPost.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("is_active", isActive));
```

Note: I wish to only get the data from comma separated ids with active records. You can say it's working like `OR` condition in MySQL. We need to change it to AND condition I'm trying but not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just replace `must` with `filter`.

Alternatively, you need just another layer of `bool` query.

```
String[] array = assignedCategories.split(",");
for (String value : array) {
  queryBuilderPost.should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("faq_id", value));
}
QueryBuilder bool = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
bool.must(queryBuilderPost);
bool.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("is_active", isActive));
```

And then use `bool` as your query.

Comment: thank you very much @anton Lashin , 

BTW already find the solution , same as your answer , thanks buddy <3 


  `BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
  BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilderPost = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();`